# What is the conceptual difference between a Plotly Dash layout and a component?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, plotly.js

What is the conceptual boundary/difference between a Plotly Dash layout and a component?

I.e. in which cases should I make something **a re-usable, custom component using ReactJS** (as described under https://dash.plotly.com/plugins ) and in which cases should I make **a layout or part of it re-usable by wrapping it into a plain old Python function** (as described in the Reusable Components section under https://dash.plotly.com/layout )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR; try creating a layout in Dash. If it doesn't work, performs poorly, or requires lots of hacks, create a React component instead.

As a rule of thumb, I would use layouts in Dash *whenever I can*. Simply because the process of creating a layout is (at least for me) much faster as compared to writing a React component. This is one of the main reasons I use Dash in the first place.

To elaborate a bit more, there is a lot of things that you *cannot* do in Dash (or that are tedious, performs poorly and/or require elaborate hacks). Typical examples are bi-directional state synchronization and interaction with libraries that require passing function handles as arguments (which is not possible from Dash). In these cases, a React component is the best (only) option.